# Jquery date picker not working inside gridview Update panel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I want to display calender on Gridview item template on calender click.for this I am using Jquery date picker .But Jquery date picker working fine if gridview is not inside update panel.But as Gridview is inside update panel,Jquery date picker not working.Please suggest.

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.dynDateTime.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/calendar-en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $jq141 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$jq141(document).ready(function () {
    $jq141(".Calender").dynDateTime({
        showsTime: true,
        ifFormat: "%d-%b-%Y ",
        daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m,  %Y",
        align: "BR",
        electric: false,
        singleClick: false,
        displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
        button: ".next()"
    });
});
```

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPUpdate" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%"
                                CssClass="grid-view" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
                                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternate" />
                                <RowStyle CssClass="normal" />
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="header" />
                                <Columns>


                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOB" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" Text='<%# Eval("DOB", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")%>'
                                                runat="server" Width="80px" class="Calender"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <img src="/_layouts/images/ITEVENT.PNG" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                            </asp:GridView>
                            <div id="Div1" style="padding: 2px; float: right" runat="server">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" align="right" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                                <input type="button" class="btnClose" value="Cancel" id="btnclose" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnRefesh" runat="server" Text="RefeshSPDRDD" OnClick="btnRefesh_Click"
                                    Visible="false" />
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" />
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRefesh" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: `class="Calender"` or `CssClass="Calender"` ???

Comment: Use  **LIKE selector** using Jquery

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id$=txtDOB]").datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif'
            });
        });
     </script>
```

- OR

  `$jq141(document).ready(function () {
      $jq141("[id$=txtDOB]").dynDateTime({
          showsTime: true,
          ifFormat: "%d-%b-%Y ",
          daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m,  %Y",
          align: "BR",
          electric: false,
          singleClick: false,
          displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
          button: ".next()"
      });
  });`

You need to change just this : `$jq141("[id$=txtDOB]").dynDateTime(...)`

Answer (score 0):

This resolves my problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $jq141 = $.noConflict(true);
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function DocumentReadyCalenderMethods() {

    $jq141(document).ready(function () {
        $jq141(".Calender").dynDateTime({
            showsTime: true,
            ifFormat: "%d-%b-%Y ",
            daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m,  %Y",
            align: "BR",
            electric: false,
            singleClick: true,
            displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
            button: ".next()"
           // autoClose: true
        });
    });

}


function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
        DocumentReadyCalenderMethods();
    }
}
```